# Drupal function to delete folder

Tags: files

How I created the folder i want to delete:

```
$form['logo'] = array(
'#title' => t('Upload logo'),
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#description' => t('Allowed extensions: .gif .png .jpg'),
'#upload_location' => 'public://myfolder/',
'#upload_validators' => array(
  'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
  'file_validate_image_resolution' => array('500x250'),
),);
```

Now how to delete it? I have tried this

`file_unmanaged_delete_recursive('public://myfolder/');`

and

```
drupal_rmdir('public://myfolder/');
```

There are files in the folder I'm trying to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_unmanaged` functions are allowed to fail on managed items, so when you create folder using `'#type' => 'managed_file'`, they are not the way to go.

`drupal_rmdir` is only a wrapper around PHP [`rmdir`](http://php.net/rmdir), and it requires folder to be empty.

It means both solutions you have tried was not able to work.

---

Correct way is to use [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to load all files in the folder you want to purge, then use [`file_delete`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_delete/7) on them, with `$force` set to `TRUE` to remove files that are in use (think twice if that's really what you want to do!). Only when the folder is empty, call [`drupal_rmdir`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_rmdir/7) on it.